# Measuring processing time in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I need to measure the time it takes for MonetDB to return all relevant data in response to a query. Based on my research, I have found a few potential solutions:

1. Measure wall-clock time when sending the query to mclient via the command line (e.g., "time mclient -s [query]"). But this involves the overhead of loading and starting mclient.
2. Use the timer in interactive mode. But, from my understanding, this only gives me the time from when the server receives the query and returns the first block of data.
3. Use the Trace command. But measurements using trace apparently have high overheads.

Is there a way to measure the time from when the query arrives at the server, and the "last" block of relevant data is returned?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not to use `select now();`? e.g. `select now();YOUR_SQLQUERY;select now();` and then you know the start and end times.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this would definitely work. Sorry for my lack of SQL knowledge :-(

Comment: I'm always using /usr/bin/time mclient ...., e.g. `/usr/bin/time mclient somedb -s "select 1"`. This takes 0.00 seconds, so overhead is limited. But if your queries are in the millisecond range, this is of course not accurate enough.

Comment: Also, have in mind that MonetDB is self-indexing, first query will take more time then consecutive times, and as far as I know there is little to no control over this exposed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
select now();
YOUR_SQL_QUERY;
select now();
```

and now you know the start and end times.